# Angular with Auth0 call to backend

Tags: angular, auth0

I'm having a hard time with setting up a correct way to do an authorized get to my ASP.NET web api.

I followed these examples: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs2-systemjs-sample

I can login and receive a token from the auth0 server, but then I need to do a get to my back-end server and I don't know what the proper to do this in Angular is.

Angular code:

```
let headers: any = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        };

        this.authHttp.get('http://localhost:58105/api/ping/secure', {headers: headers})
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('Request Complete')
            );
```

But then I receive this in my console:

```
AuthHttpError {originalStack: "Error: No JWT present or has expired↵    at AuthHt…ules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11806:138)", zoneAwareStack: "Error: No JWT present or has expired↵    at AuthHt…ules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11806:138)", stack: "Error: No JWT present or has expired↵    at AuthHt…ules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11806:138)", message: "No JWT present or has expired"}
```

I'm missing something but I don't know what, if I look to the examples they never give the token to the header, does this mean AuthHttp solves this for us?

I really need to get this working?